# Trigger in SQL Management Studio not working as it should

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to create a trigger in the 'CabecDoc' table so that it adds a field to the 'Test' table (the field being 'Artigo').

I thought this trigger would do the trick, but it doesn't! It does nothing! It does not create any record on my 'Test' table. Can you help?

```
USE [PRICLONEPRJ]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CriarContrato] 
   ON  [dbo].[CabecDoc] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    set ansi_warnings on 
    set ansi_nulls on
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Test (Artigo)
    select LinhasDoc.Artigo
    from inserted   INNER JOIN
                  LinhasDoc ON inserted.Id = LinhasDoc.IdCabecDoc 

END
```

Comment: Is the JOIN maybe not matching on any row from `LinhasDoc`?

Comment: I don't believe so. I did a simple test where I created a table with a single record to mimic what the 'inserted' table should contain and then tested this code in a query window and it seemed to work. The result was a single value...Is there any way to debug this code within SMSS?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to debug this code within SMSS?

Try insert this row

```
EXEC xp_logevent 60000, 'CriarContrato works', informational;
```

at the begining of trigger body. And then you should see this log in SSMS - Object Explorer - Management - Sql Server Logs - Current

If it works, you can add this after INSERT:

```
declare @log varchar(2048) = CONCAT('CriarContrato inserted ', @@ROWCOUNT, ' rows');
EXEC xp_logevent 60000, @log, informational;
```

or something else.

Comment: Thanks! It does work...i do get the 'CriarContrato works' message...good to know! I'm now wondering...because I need to get information from another table (LinhasDoc) which is not the table i'm creating a record to (CabecDoc), is it possible that, at the time the trigger fires, the LinhasDoc table hasn't been updated yet?

Comment: @Rui Barreiros - is it possible that, at the time the trigger fires, the LinhasDoc table hasn't been updated yet?

yes, of course. show your code where you insert in CabecDoc and update LinhasDoc

Comment: Thanks Ruslan K.! I get a Incorrect syntax near '+' message when I try to update the trigger...am I adding this in the wrong place? I placed it in the line before END

Comment: "show your code where you insert in CabecDoc and update LinhasDoc "...well I don't! i'm changing an existing database which already has that logic of updating other tables when a record in CabecDoc is created...is there any way to wait for all other triggers to run before my trigger is fired?

Comment: > Incorrect syntax near '+' message

Yes, updated answer. 

> is there any way to wait for all other triggers to run before my trigger is fired?

I didn't know this way. Hard to advise without seeing the whole code...